# Nice ready to use /etc/init.d/ros script

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just trying to make my ROS automatically run proper roslaunch command on headless system. I hope someone already made nice scriptwork?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9666/nice-ready-to-use-/etc/init.d/ros-script/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Here is the functions we use in our init.d file to start / stop ros. It prints the output of the node in tty8 and tty9. It could be combined with screen for easier use as well.

```
start_ros () {
    source /opt/ros/setup.sh

    roscore <>/dev/tty8 2>/dev/tty8 & disown
    until rostopic list ; do sleep 1; done
    roslaunch YOUR_PACKAGE YOUR_LAUNCH_FILE.launch <> /dev/tty9 2>/dev/tty9 & disown
}

stop_ros () {
    source /opt/ros/setup.sh

    #killall nodes
    for i in $( rosnode list ); do
    rosnode kill $i;
    done

    #stop roscore
    killall roscore
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't found an example script, but there are two mailing list conversations about this problem where they talk about how to write one (what steps need to be in the script) that might be helpful for you.

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Best-way-to-start-a-launch-file-automatically-on-startup-td1768616.html

http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/auto-start-ROS-launch-script-on-boot-up-td1687093.html

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2011-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1